# How to use datatable in java as we use in .net

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

I worked in .net over 1-2 years where I dealt with data table that's an amazing to use. But now I moved to java for android and java apps but I didn't find any tabular object like data table in .net.

I found arrays, Lists and list view.
I want to make sure that is there any tabular form object where I can play in form of rows and columns.

Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db does this help?

Comment: Are you searching for a layout or a way to connect with your database?

Comment: A [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) in Android is the closest object to a .NET DataTable.